# Android Things : DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog not shown

Tags: android-datepicker, android-timepicker, android-things

I try to show `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` in Android Things app but instead of dialogs, i obtain black screen. (When i tap on this black screen, i go back to the calling activity)

I can see the following message in Android Monitor :

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   (Number of frames varies)

Did somebody encounter this problem ? Are `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` supported on Android Things ? What am i doing wrong or missing ?

(I use Android Things 0.5.0-devpreview on RPi3)

Example code :
https://gist.github.com/aberteau/64343514b456693568f4003ea7682cb6

Thanks you in advance for your help.

Comment: @Amael it's always necessary, much more likely to get people answering you when they can reproduce the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved in 0.5.1-devpreview.